# Update components without processing in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to update a component without processing it. I use a binding get the value of a checkbox and decide if the other component should be rendered. Unfortunately, the update? or the binding? doesn't work as i would.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isPercentage" value="#{myBean.isDiscountInPercentage}" 
  label="Percentage" binding="#{discountInPercentage}">
  <p:ajax process="" update="outpDiscountValue" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:outputPanel id="outpDiscountValue">
  <h:outputLabel value="$" rendered="#{!discountInPercentage.value}" />
  <h:outputLabel value="%" rendered="#{discountInPercentage.value}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I don't think you understand clearly what the real problem is. The value binding for `isPercentage` is in the backing bean no? So there's no way it's value will be updated without going to the server and running thru the full lifecycle or "processing it" as you say. Why are you using the `binding` attribute. Or better yet, what are you expecting it to provide you?

Comment: I'm probably missunderstanding this binding attribute. But is it possible to know if a checkbox is ticked without updating the bean. Just in the xhtml page?

Comment: You can check it with Javascript. I'll post an answer

Comment: Ok, thx for your answer. Post it if youw ant me to accept it.